# Bash array iteration direction and performance

Tags: arrays, bash, performance, iteration, direction

Could someone explain what is the cause of the severe slowdown when iterating bash arrays backwards?

Example:

`time bash -c 'arr=();for i in {1..100000}; do arr+=( $i );done; echo "Straight"; i=0;while (( $i < 100000 )); do current_element=${arr[$i]}; ((i++));done'`

```
Straight

real    0m0.270s
user    0m0.269s
sys 0m0.002s
```

`time bash -c 'arr=();for i in {1..100000}; do arr+=( $i );done; echo "Reverse"; i=99999;while (( $i > 0 )); do current_element=${arr[$i]}; ((i--));done'`

```
Reverse

real    0m25.569s
user    0m25.589s
sys 0m0.008s
```

Also

```
${arr[i-1]} + ${arr[i]}
```

is much faster than

```
${arr[i]} + ${arr[i-1]}
```

Thanks for your time.

Edit:

> bash --version
>
> GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: very interesting. I suspect only someone intimately familiar with the bash implementation will be able to provide an answer. For those hoping to get intimate: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/

Comment: Please add bash version to your question.

Comment: `bash` "arrays" are actually doubly-linked lists, so the naive expectation is that `{$arr[$i]}` should be an O(n) operation whether `i` is increasing or decreasing. It looks like there may be some sort of caching optimization that makes access faster for increasing `i`. This makes sense given the primary use case is to pass the contents of an array as positional parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found some info on the matter.

According to http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

> Arrays in Bash are (circularly) linked lists of type string (char *).

I guess this means that the passed elements are sought from the beginning of the array each time, hence the slowdown. (eg: if we are at i, in order to get to i-1, we should start looking from 0)

Also found a related post with some more info on the matter:
http://spencertipping.com/posts/2013.0814.bash-is-irrecoverably-broken.html